# SharePoint Calculatted column

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column

I need to create a calculated column to get the number `7261` from the string below.

Sometimes it can be 4 digits, sometimes 5, so cant use exact character count.

I tried to use the FIND option and say Find `, Serial` which will work but gives me all the info before `,Serial` rather than just the 4 characters `7261`.

Please help.

String :

`service report for notification: 404-ED-GREYN-007261, Serial 69530, 999003550472-0003`

Comment: Hi, 
What is the pattern to get these numbers? i.e. is there any criteria to decide on why we have to fetch five characters instead of four characters? 
Should these extracted characters be always at the end of the string?

Comment: its actually from a email subject line..

Answer (score 1):

This will return just the four digits:

```
=MID( [yourColumnName], FIND("Serial", [yourColumnName] ) - 6, 4 )
```

This will return all six digits, including leading zeros:

```
=MID( [yourColumnName], FIND("Serial", [yourColumnName] ) - 8, 6 )
```

This will return the number (1-6 digits) without the leading zeros:

```
=0 + MID( [yourColumnName], FIND("Serial", [yourColumnName] ) - 8, 6 )
```

The above assumes the exact format from your sample and that the value will never be blank.

To deal with misformatted data or a blank:

```
=IF( ISERR( FIND("Serial",[yourColumnName]) ), 
     "n/a",  
     MID([yourColumnName],FIND("Serial",[yourColumnName])-6,4) )
```

Comment: that is FANTASTIC... this is great,, i did have to change the end "-7,5))" instead of "-6,4))", sometimes they come in with 5 characters ie. 17261 or 07261, i wish i could add something to the logic where if the first character is '0' of 07261 then strip the '0' and leave 7261.     THANK you so much Mike .. i have been banging my head on this all afternoon....

Comment: one more,, i do like this one =0 + MID( [Subject], FIND("Serial", [Subject] ) - 8, 6 ),,,, but it adds in a comma   ie. 7,261

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(LEFT(MID([Title],FIND("Serial",Title)-7,5),1)="0",RIGHT(MID([Title],FIND("Serial",Title)-7,5),4),MID([Title],FIND("Serial",Title)-7,5))
```

Here is my test:
[image]

Comment: fricken amazing, works like a charm, thank SOO much man.

Comment: Welcome. Please accept if it helped you.